# Entire function $f$ such that $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} |f(z)|=\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem**

Let $f$ be an entire non constant function such that $\lim_{|z| \to \infty} |f(z)|=\infty$. Prove that $f$ has a positive and finite number of zeros.

If $f$ is entire, then $f$ can we written as $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^n$. Also, for $M=1$, there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $z \geq N$, $f(z)>1$.

I got stuck here, from above, all I know is that the zeros of $f$ are isolated and that they have to be in the unit disk $\{|z|<N\}$. How can I prove from here that the set of zeros if finite but not empty? (I suppose that positive number of zeros means that there is at least one zero). I would appreciate some help.

Comment: What does $\lim\limits_{\lvert z\rvert\to \infty} \lvert f(z)\rvert = \infty$ tell you about the singularity that $f$ has at $\infty$?

Comment: Hint for positive number of zeroes: Look at ${1 \over f}$. Hint for finite number of zeroes: zeroes are isolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1** Since $\lim_{z \to \infty} |f(z)| = \infty$ then there exists some $R$ so that $|f(z)|>1$ for all $|z| >R$. What can you say about the zeroes of $f$?

**Hint 2** To prove that the number of zeroes is positive: Assume by contradiction that $f$ has no zeroes.

Then $\frac{1}{f}$ is entire. Moreover, with $R$ as in **Hint 1**, $\frac{1}{f}$ is bounded on $|z| >R$.

Moreover, as it is continuous, $\frac{1}{f}$ must be bounded on the compact set $|z| \leq R$.

This proves that $\frac{1}{f}$ is entire and bounded, which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: The zeros of $f$ must be on the compact set $S=\{|z|\leq R\}$. By what you've said, there is at least one zero on that set. Now, as $S$ is compact and the zeros are isolated, then the set has to be finite (using the definition of open finite covers of compact sets is it easy to show by contradiction that the zeros must be finite).

Comment: @user156441 Yup.